# YouCompleteMe and C++ diagnostics inappropriate errors

Tags: c++, c++11, vim, exuberant-ctags, juce

I'm trying to get YCM working in Vim for C++ development. I'm using the JUCE framework. Ctags and autocompletion are working great. However, I'm getting lots of wrong errors come up in the 'gutter' as red arrows.

E.g.

```
no matching member function for call to 'addAndMakeVisible'
```

when `addAndMakeVisible` is a function of an inherited class `Component` and even comes up in the autocomplete.

Also getting lots of errors like the following:

```
cannot initialize object parameter of type 'juce::Component' with an expression of type 'MyComponent'
```

My `.ycm_extra_conf.py`: https://gist.github.com/adamski/a793a24b026f68a1074e
I am adding the JUCE libraries with absolute path as well as the local project version, and copied suggestion from @ladislas example.

Output of :YCMDebugInfo
https://gist.github.com/adamski/2e7dd79b45d0fb6f5010#file-ycmdebuginfo

Current output of :YCMDiags https://gist.github.com/adamski/8fad8e0724a03854912b

example repository that recreates the problem: https://github.com/adamski/juce-chapter02-07

My `.vimrc` looks like:

```
"" YouCompleteMe options
"
let g:ycm_register_as_syntastic_checker = 0 "default 1
"let g:Show_diagnostics_ui = 1 "default 1
"
""will put icons in Vim's gutter on lines that have a diagnostic set.
"Turning this off will also turn off the YcmErrorLine and YcmWarningLine
""highlighting
set tags=./tags,tags;
set autochdir
let g:ycm_enable_diagnostic_signs = 1
let g:ycm_enable_diagnostic_highlighting = 1
let g:ycm_always_populate_location_list = 1 "default 0
let g:ycm_open_loclist_on_ycm_diags = 1 "default 1
let g:ycm_seed_identifiers_with_syntax = 1

let g:ycm_complete_in_strings = 1 "default 1
let g:ycm_collect_identifiers_from_tags_files = 1 "default 0
let g:ycm_path_to_python_interpreter = '' "default ''


let g:ycm_server_use_vim_stdout = 0 "default 0 (logging to console)
let g:ycm_server_log_level = 'info' "default info


let g:ycm_global_ycm_extra_conf = '~/.ycm_extra_conf.py'  "where to search for .ycm_extra_conf.py if not found

let g:ycm_confirm_extra_conf = 1

let g:ycm_goto_buffer_command = 'same-buffer' "[ 'same-buffer', 'horizontal-split', 'vertical-split', 'new-tab' ]
let g:ycm_filetype_whitelist = { '*': 1 }
let g:ycm_key_invoke_completion = '<C-Space>'

nnoremap <F11> :YcmForceCompileAndDiagnostics <CR>
```

Comment: .... And where is your `.ycm_extra_conf.py`? But honestly unless it is something trivial we probably won't be able to help since each `.ycm_extra_conf.py` needs to tailored to the project you are working on since you need to pass all the compilation flags to YouCompleteMe (especially the `-I` for the includes)

Comment: OK, I will look into it further, I am using the default `.ycm_extra_conf.py` obviously need to check compilation flags.. I am using XCode so maybe i can find the flags in the settings there.

Comment: There is no default `.ycm_extra_conf.py` file. There is only the one that is used for the YouCompleteMe source code which is there as an example. It is not meant to work on everyone's project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @FDinoff pointed out, every `.ycm_extra_conf.py` needs to be tailored for its own project.

To give you an example that might help you, here is mine : [`.ycm_extra_conf.py`](https://github.com/WeAreLeka/Bare-Arduino-Project/blob/master/.ycm_extra_conf.py)

Because I put all my libs inside a `./lib` directory at the root of my projects, I've made a little script to automatically scan the directories and add the libraries as flags.

You can read it [line 57](https://github.com/WeAreLeka/Bare-Arduino-Project/blob/master/.ycm_extra_conf.py#L57):

```
  for path, dirs, files in os.walk(libDir):
    for d in dirs:
      flag = '-I' + os.path.join(path, d)
      flags.append(flag)
```

`libDir` is defined [line 4](https://github.com/WeAreLeka/Bare-Arduino-Project/blob/master/.ycm_extra_conf.py#L4)

And here is the original project: [Moti](https://github.com/WeAreLeka/moti)

**EDIT - 12/02/2014** -

I don't see the `.ycm_extra_conf.py` in your tree output. This file should be at the root of your project.

Also you can try using absolute path for your flags.

The output of `:YcmDebugInfo` should look like that : http://pastebin.com/WARSUiML

You can check my `.vimrc` where I configure YCM : [Link to YCM Conf](https://github.com/ladislas/nvim/blob/master/vimrc#L225). Try using mine without yours to see what happens.

Comment: Nice project, you should add a link to your site on your README. It is currently not very easy to find.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I used your example to adjust my ```.ycm_extra_conf.py``` but still get the errors come up. I am explicitly adding the full absolute path to Juce library too. Updating question.

Comment: @Adamski can you show me the output of `:YcmDebugIngo` and `:YcmDiags` in a gist please.

Comment: @Adamski and also, can you show us the output of `tree` inside your project directory or a link to github (even better)

Comment: That was the problem, was at the root of my home folder not root of project!

Comment: OK just realised it helped but still have the main issue of wrong errors coming up - I forgot I had switched off the diagnostics.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66099/discussion-between-ladislas-and-adamski).

Answer (score 1):

For me YouCompleteMe works great in conjunction with JUCE without the false errors you're describing.

I have copied the .ycm_extra_conf.py from my current project to the opensource predecessor for you where YCM also works as expected.

Get it from https://github.com/klangfreund/LUFSMeter . Either YCM works as expected (Somthing is wrong with your project) or it doesn't (Something is wrong with you installation of YCM).

Comment: Thanks for that, however still get false errors with your `.ycm_extra_conf.py`, also tried running the YCM `./install.sh` script again. I am on OSX 10.9 with Xcode  5.1.1. 
I'll try downloading your whole project to know for sure...

Answer (score 1):

I installed the XCode update to 6.11, and it now seems to be working as expected. 
Thanks to @ladislas and @Samuel Gaehwiler for the help and pointers.